# How can I suppress a terminal ligature?

Tags: ligatures

The standard techniques for suppressing ligatures, such as inserting an empty group, or placing the characters that would normally form a ligature individually in groups, do not seem to work for ligatures that are formed on account of being terminal.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[longs]{pacaslon}
\begin{document}
foss. fosse.
\end{document}
```

Here, the double ess in "foss" becomes an long-ess-short-ess ligature (the character is basically the same as an eszet, and uses that codepoint in the Adobe fonts), while that in "fosse" becomes a double-long-ess ligature. There is a rule that when a double-ess occurs at the end of an abbreviation before a full stop (period), it should not remain a double-long-ess ligature, not a long-ess-short-ess.

So my question is, how can I suppress that ligature? Note that double ess becomes long-ess-short-ess at the end of a word, so merely writing e.g. "{foss}." won't change the outcome. Also, writing "fo{ſ}{ſ}" (i.e. separately grouping two long esses) won't work, as I want a long ess ligature. And that doesn't have a code point, so I can't easily write it, but if I could, it would immediately, finding itself at the end of a word, turn back into a long-ess-short-ess.

Currently, the only solution I can find is to remove the ligatures turning double-long-ess into long-ess-short-ess before period from the TFM files, but then I have manually to add an empty group {} before almost every period (i.e. every period EXCEPT those denoting an abbreviation), which is error-prone and tedious.

Since I can't find the acaslon package online any more, I've put a copy up at: 
http://rrt.adsensus.net/acaslon.zip

Comment: Try with `foss\noboundary.`

Comment: I get a 404 from that link, please check.

Comment: Is using LuaTeX an option for you? If so, consider using the `selnolig` package, as it lets you define ligature suppression rules for the word(s) you mention.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use LuaTeX, owing to microtype features that it doesn't yet support (at least, not without upgrades I'm not yet prepared to make). I'll test the \noboundary command as soon as I can, which, if it works, is an entirely reasonable solution.

Comment: foss\noboundary does the trick. @egreg, could you make that an answer so I can mark it as such? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX has a primitive that is just for cases like this one. If a character is followed (or preceded) by `\noboundary`, then no boundary ligature for that character is used. So

```
foss\noboundary.
```

should be the solution. The period would trigger the boundary ligature, but the `\noboundary` item neutralizes it.